# BASH specific ip address for specific device

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can't seem to get this thing to work. I need to verify specific ip address on a specific card. I created a simple function, that receives two variables, the device name (`$1`) and ip address (`$2`). I need to also return the value of true/false (0/1). The test works properly (I used debug code) but the return value is always empty. It needs to be a function because, it will be called several times. I have tried several variations on return value all seem to return blank. This was my latest iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash

function ip_addr_tst()
{ 
    ip addr show dev $1|fgrep -q "$2"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        retval=0
        echo "found"
    else
        retval=1
        echo "not found"
    fi
    return "$retval"
}

answer=$(ip_addr_tst ens192 192.168.2.180)
echo $answer
```

Comment: it works for me on a centos-7 box. What linux are you using, and can you explain what you mean by "test works properly" ?

Comment: Your code is working on my linux except it echoes found/not found whereas if you expect to get 0/1 you have to check the function return code with a `echo $?` instead of a `echo $answer`

Answer (score 0):

so I used echo $? and it worked.  I tested with false and true Network cards/Ip addresses and it worked perfectly.  Just so people can see

function ip_addr_tst()
{

ip addr show dev $1|fgrep -q "$2"

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    retval=0
    echo "found"
else
    retval=1
    echo "not found"
fi
return "$retval"
```

}

answer=$(ip_addr_tst ens192 192.168.2.180)

echo $?